# Should I free char* initialized using string-literals?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Should I free `char*` variables when they were initialized using string literals? To me, the syntax would lead me to the assumption that they are only stack-allocated, but this example showed me, they are not.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char* globalBuffer;

typedef struct Container {
    char* buffer;
} Container;

Container* Container_new(char* buffer) {
    Container* container = malloc(sizeof(Container));
    container->buffer    = buffer;
    globalBuffer         = buffer;
    return container;
}

void Container_print(Container* container) {
    if (container->buffer != NULL) {
        printf("%s", container->buffer);
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Container contains a NULL-buffer.");
    }
}

Container* stage() {
    Container* container = Container_new("Test-string.");
    Container_print(container);
    return container;
}

int main() {
    Container* container = stage();
    Container_print(container);

    free(container);
    Container_print(container); // I know, this results in undefined behaviour

    printf(globalBuffer);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\niklas\Desktop>gcc char_test.c

C:\Users\niklas\Desktop>a.exe
Test-string.
Test-string.
­6>
Test-string.

C:\Users\niklas\Desktop>
```

So, the `char*` initialized with string-literals does still exist, even it got out of scope.

So, my question, should I free such `char*` pointers? Would this be the correct `main()`?

```
int main() {
    Container* container = stage();
    Container_print(container);

    free(container->buffer);    // NEW
    free(container);
    Container_print(container);

    printf(globalBuffer);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW - Your `printf(globalBuffer)` and `printf(container->buffer);` will give you jip if they contain the % character.

Comment: Sometimes a bit of meta reasoning can help: do you really believe a fundamental concept such as string literals can only be used correctly if accompanied by cleanup code? Surely not.

Comment: NO, you may not do that. You use free() only with memory that's been dynamically allocated with malloc( ), calloc(),  or realloc( ).

Comment: To clarify, string literals are not allocated on the stack, either. They're allocated statically, meaning they're baked into the program data and loaded into memory when the program is loaded. All pointers to the strings are pointers to that location in the program data. They are neither stack nor heap. If they were allocated on the stack, then you would not be able to return them from functions safely.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

String literals are stored in such a way that they're available for the lifetime of the program; if you write

```
char *ptr = "This is a test";
```

all that's written to `ptr` is the *address* of the string literal `"This is a test"`.  Even if the `ptr` variable goes out of scope, the string literal continues to exist in its own section of memory, which is *not* the same section used by `malloc` (at least, not at a logical level).  Note that multiple instances of the same string literal *may* resolve to the same location; IOW, given

```
char *p0 = "This is a test";
char *p1 = "This is a test";
```

`p0` and `p1` may both contain the same address (it's up to the compiler whether multiple occurrences of string literals are mapped to the same location or not).

When you call `Container_new`, all you're doing is copying an *address* to `container->buffer` and `globalBuffer`; both wind up pointing to the same thing that exists independently of either of them.  `free`-ing `container` doesn't affect the string literal that `container->buffer` points to, so `printf(globalBuffer);` still displays `"Test-string."`.

In summary, you should *not* call

```
free(container->buffer);
```

for this particular program, since you didn't assign the result of a `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` call to it.

If, OTOH, you had written `Container_new` as

```
Container* Container_new(char* buffer) 
{
  Container* container = malloc(sizeof(Container));
  container->buffer    = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);  // Allocate memory to 
  if (container->buffer)                              // store a *new* instance
  {                                                   // of the input string. 
    strcpy(container->buffer, buffer);                // This will need to be 
  }                                                   // freed before freeing
  globalBuffer         = buffer;                      // the container
  return container;
}
```

then you *would* need to free `container->buffer` before freeing `container`.

Answer (score 41):

**You shall never `free()` memory that you did not `malloc()`ed.**

The way the compiler implements string-literals is not your business: it's an implementation detail. You can `free()` a pointer to memory that you allocated using `malloc()`, and only those, or you are risking the life of your system.

Ideally, `malloc()` calls and `free()` calls should appear on the same "design level" (inside the same implementation file for the same module for example), and they should match perfectly: one `free()` for each `malloc()`. but that's not always possible.

*(Note that some library allocates blocks of memory, returns pointers to those blocks, and instructs you to free them. in this case, you are allowed to free those pointers, but that is a bad design practice from the people who created the library.)*

Comment: Now that I look it up, it doesn't look like it's part of the standard at all. It's in POSIX.

Comment: @Mysticial and also why I say "don't use `strdup`" every time and every place I see it

Comment: Well, if you're going to complain about `strdup`, you could complain about `calloc` and `realloc` too...

Comment: If it's bad design for libraries to give you pointers and tell you to free them when you don't need them anymore... what is the right way of handling freeing memory malloc'd by libraries?

Comment: @SzerémiAttila : the library should provide you with a function call to free the memory it has allocated. this ensures that the correct function is called to free the pointer (depending on the runtime used and the way the library is linked, `malloc()` and `free()` may not be the same inside or outside the library)