# Pointers To Const Char

Tags: c, pointers, char, string-literals

The following code points to the first character in a *char array* available in read-only memory. Is that right?:

```
const char * ptr = "String one";
```

Now when `ptr` starts to point at another memory location:

```
ptr = "String two";
```

What happens to the first *char array*? Is that memory location freed when the execution ends?

Comment: String literals are static allocations. They do not need to be freed.

Comment: Check this question too: [Should I free char* initialized using string-literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504588/should-i-free-char-initialized-using-string-literals)

Comment: Why should it be freed ? the pointer just points to a different string literal and as explained in the accepted answer the string literals have static storage duration so they ain't freed .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard only says that string literals have *static storage duration*, which means that the lifetime of the variable is until the program ends and it is initialized when the program starts. The relevant section in the [C11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is `6.4.5` paragraph *6*:

> [...] The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence. [...]

It could be in read only memory and probably is but that is implementation defined. It does not need to be freed, only memory that is dynamically allocated via `malloc` needs a subsequent call to `free`.

If I use this program:

```
int main()
{
    const char * ptr = "String one";

    return 0;   
}
```

and we build it with `gcc` and then use `objdump`:

```
objdump -s -j .rodata a.out
```

We will find that in this case it is indeed stored in the read only data section:

```
Contents of section .rodata:
  400580 01000200 53747269 6e67206f 6e6500    ....String one.
```

You can run it yourself [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6895540947d56af9dab606064fa9209a-f37ccd9fde735da9113f829339b56ada)

Comment: So it will be automatically deleted from memory when the program is closed?

Comment: @2013Asker Yes, when your program exits it will release it resources to the system.

Comment: On a typical hosted implementation, a string literal will probably be in memory that's marked as read-only by the operating system, not in physical ROM, and all your program's memory will almost certainly be released when the program finishes. On a freestanding implementation, it could be a different story; a very low-level system might run just one program, whose code and static data are stored in ROM that's never erased.