# Do i required to cleanup the curl_easy_strerror buffer?

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I wrote wrapper over curl library API's in c++. And I am trying to use if for request/response in c++.Sometimes the request failed before it send to server as curl api's return some strerror.I am transferring that string error to my application.Do I need to clean it?

My code looks like as follows,

```
int HttpClientImplCurl::get(void*& aOutBuf, base::Size& aOutSize,void*& aOutRecvHeaderBuf, base::Size& aOutRecvHeaderSize, const char*& errorBuff)
{
        HttpClientImplCurlCleaner    lCleaner(this); // Cleans up when it goes out of context
        struct curl_slist*          lHeaders = NULL;

        // setup get
        CURLcode lCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL,
                                          aInClient.getUrl().getBuffer());

        if (lCode != 0) {
            errorBuff = curl_easy_strerror(lCode);
            return lCode;
        }

}
```

I am doing curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandle) in my destructor.

Here I am setting curl_easy_strerror to my const char*& errorBuff. which I am using in application. Should I do a free(errorBuff)?

Or any curl library api, which I need to use to clean up similar to

```
struct curl_slist*          lHeaders = NULL;
 lHeaders = curl_slist_append(lHeaders,lMultiHeader.getBuffer());
 curl_slist_free_all(lHeaders);?
```

Or it doesn't required and curl_easy_cleanup will take care the clean up?

Answer (score 4):

> I am setting curl_easy_strerror... Should I do a free(errorBuff)?

No.

The [curl_easy_strerror](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_strerror.html) function uses a [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) to hold the error string which is returned as a `const char *` pointer[1].

You [must not free it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9505236/1688185).

[1] with `const char *p`, `p`  points to constant characters. You cannot change the contents.