# Why don't I have to use free() after allocating without malloc()

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, dynamic-allocation

Everybody knows that you have to `free()` pointers, when you use `malloc()` because the memory is allocated in the heap, which is not kept account of by the process.

But why don't I have to use `free()` when assigning a pointer without a heap:

```
char* text0 = calloc(20, sizeof (char));
strncpy(text0, "Hello World", 20);  // Remember to use `free()`!
char* text1 = "Goodbye World!"; // No need for `free()`?
```

Isn't `text1` also a pointer on the stack pointing to the memory allocated on the heap? Why is there no need for free()?

Comment: You don't allocate the memory so you don't free it.

Comment: None of your code is anywhere near correct. Have you tried compiler warnings and pedantic mode?

Comment: You do have a memory leak.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9505236/362589

Comment: "Isn't text1 also a pointer on the stack pointing to the memory allocated on the heap?" -> no. It's a pointer into a static data section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string constant `"Goodbye World!"` is placed in a global, read-only section of memory at program startup.  It is *not* allocated on the heap.  Same goes for `"Hello World"`.

So after the assignment, `text1` points to this static string.  Since the string does not exist on the heap, there's no need to call free.

Answer (score 3):

`free` must be used for all memory allocated with `malloc`. You allocate memory from the heap and must return it so you can use it later again.

```
char* text0 = calloc(20, sizeof(char));    // this memory must be freed.
```

In:

```
text0 = "Hello World";
```

you ovewrite the pointer to the allocated memory. The memory is now lost and cannot be reclaimed/reused again.

Note the parenthesis around `char` in `sizeof(char)` and note that I dropped the `*` before `text0` as you are assigning the address of the constant string to a variable of type "pointer to character". Turn warnings on when compiling!

You should have done:

```
free(text0);
text0 = "Hello World";  // DON'T use `free()`!
```

Note again I dropped the `*`. More reasons to turn warnings on when compiling.

```
char* text1 = "Goodbye World!"; // No need for `free()`?
```

No, no need to call free because you did not allocate from the heap.

Comment: Your answer has some problems. `sizeof char` requires parens. `*text0 = "..."` is wrong as `*text0` is a `char`.

Comment: @Cool-Guy, parenthesis around `sizeof char`: that is his code and later I tell him to turn warnings on. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Your answer is still confusing. You say that "_You should have done: `*text0 = "Hello World";`_" But that's wrong as `*text0` is a `char` and you're trying to assign a string literal to it which makes no sense.

Comment: @Cool-guy, I fixed it. Unfortunately the text gets longer and doesn't focus on his thinking error as good anymore (a reason why I sometimes perfer to leave the minor errors in).